# JavaScript calculation won't print results

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
$(function() {
  if(document.getElementById('price') !== null && document.getElementById('dp') !== null){
    var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
    var deposite = document.getElementById('dp').value;
    document.getElementById('remained').value = parseInt(price)-parseInt(deposite);
  }
});
```

and this fields in my form

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="price">Price *</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" name="price">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="dp">DP *</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dp" name="dp">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="remained">Remained *</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="remained" name="remained">
</div>
```

The logic is simple:

1. get price
2. get DP
3. print minus results in remained input

but somehow it doesn't print anything in remained input.

**Any idea what I did wrong?**

Comment: The fields aren't filled on pageload, so won't it always print 0? Or does it not print anything at all into the `#remained`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance doesn't print anything at all, i also tried to print static text in console.log() didn't print as well

Comment: `parseInt` returns `NaN` when passed the empty string, and `NaN` can't be set to the value of a numeric input field. Don't know why you're trying to retrieve the values on pageload though, that doesn't make sense - they're empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is executing on page load and the value of the inputs are empty.

You should execute your code on some event like the following way:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#dp, #price').on('input', function(){    
    if(document.getElementById('price') !== null && document.getElementById('dp') !== null){
      var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
      var deposite = document.getElementById('dp').value;
      document.getElementById('remained').value = parseInt(price)-parseInt(deposite);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="price">Price *</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" name="price">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="dp">DP *</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dp" name="dp">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="remained">Remained *</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="remained" name="remained">
</div>
```

Comment: in 6min will be able to accept the answer please be patient :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the calculation to ready function
because it is asynchronous

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     console.log( "ready!" );
     // calculation
  });
```

Or better use angular ... Instead of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

- the calculation is right but it doen one time on page ready event
- add manual button to tell javascrip when to calculate the value
- alos add event listener to automatically call on change

---

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="price">Price *</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" name="price">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="dp">DP *</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dp" name="dp">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="remained">Remained *</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="remained" name="remained">
    </div>

    <button type="button"
    onclick="cal()">
    cal
    </button>
```

---

```
    $(function() {
      document.getElementById("price").addEventListener("change",cal);
      document.getElementById("dp").addEventListener("change",cal);
    });


    function cal(){
      if(document.getElementById('price') !== null && document.getElementById('dp') !== null){
        var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
        var deposite = document.getElementById('dp').value;
        document.getElementById('remained').value = parseInt(price)-parseInt(deposite);
      }
    }
```

Comment: that's the idea to have button but unfortunately it wasn't my interest for this case, and already fixed, thanks for the idea

Comment: thanks @mafortis , if you need any further help tag me 

Answer (score 0):

The js code runs on the initial loading of webpage. The js code must be called by an `onclick` or an `onkeyup`